# Redistribute x/y points so they dont overlap too much

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, algorithm

I have an array of objects with x/y values:

var points = [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 4}, {x: 1, y: 4}, ...];

These points are generated by translating longitude/latitude information into x/y values on a planar map. I use these vectors to place icons on a static map, by positioning them absolutely by CSS.  It works fine, but some of them do overlap slightly.

What could be done to redistribute all x/y pairs so they do not overlap as much as they would originally do? Any kind of algorithm to compare each pair and space them radially one from each other?

Comment: Increase the spacing or descrease the size of the icons? Seriously, we need more context on that, otherwise it's hard to answer and the question might even get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a spatial data structure like a PR quadtree with a minimum region size to figure out the best spacing.